# Problems setting up dbmail with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, fetchmail

Im trying to create my own mailserver using dbmail for email storage. I have configured dbmail to work with postfix following their setup guide http://www.dbmail.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/setup_postfix but when i restart postfix i get the following warnings:

```
* Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix 
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: user
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: dbname
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: hosts
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: query=SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM dbmail_aliases WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(alias, '@', -1) = '%s';
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: password
```

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and why the parameters are unused.

Comment: Can you show postfix config (/etc/postfix/main.cf)?

Comment: Read the guide carefully, you aren't supposed to put `user`, `dbname`, etc. in `main.cf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this configuration to a separate file called **virtual mailbox map**.

See documentation:

> Postfix needs to lookup if the recipient domains exist. Otherwise,
>   Postfix will reject your DBMail recipients with a “User unknown in
>   local recipient table” error.
>
> To do this, you need to enable the MySQL- or PGSQL-module in Postfix
>   and add

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
```

> After that **create the file and add the following MySQL-statements**
>   (adjust it to your needs if you use Postgres):

```
user     = <SQL-username> 
password = <SQL-password> 
hosts    = <SQL-host> 
dbname   = <SQL-database> 
query    = SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM dbmail_aliases WHERE
SUBSTRING_INDEX(alias, '@', -1) = '%s';
```

**Summarize:**

**1)** Create file:

```
nano /etc/postfix/sql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
```

**2)** Add to this file MySQL-statements above

**3)** Delete MySQL-statements from /etc/postfix/main.cf

**4)** Add to /etc/postfix/main.cf option and save changes:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
```

**5)** Reload configuration or restart Postfix:

```
service postfix reload

service postfix restart
```